# How I convert symbol to color coding shiny app

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have this shiny app; In data table if a gene carries a mutation, I show that by * otherwise by -. But, I want to color my data table to red and green for * and - respectively.

> EDITED

```
   navbarPageWithText <- function(..., text) {

  navbar <- navbarPage(...)

  textEl <- tags$p(class = "navbar-text", text)

  navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]] <- htmltools::tagAppendChild(

    navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]], textEl)

  navbar

}



# Call this function with an input (such as `textInput("text", NULL, "Search")`) if you

# want to add an input to the navbar

navbarPageWithInputs <- function(..., inputs) {

  navbar <- navbarPage(...)

  form <- tags$form(class = "navbar-form", inputs)

  navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]] <- htmltools::tagAppendChild(

    navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]], form)

  navbar

}
library(shiny)
library(DT)
Patient_005=as.data.frame(read.table(text = "   Driver  SNV_Tumour_005  SNV_Organoid_005    INDEL_Tumour_005    INDEL_Organoid_005  Deletion_Organoid_005
ABCB1   *   *   *   -   -   -
ACVR1B  *   *   -   -   -   -
ACVR2A  *   -   -   -   -   -

"))

Patient_013=as.data.frame(read.table(text = "   Driver  SNV_Tumour_013  SNV_Organoid_013    INDEL_Tumour_013    INDEL_Organoid_013  Deletion_Tumour_013 Deletion_Organoid_013
ABCB1   *   -   *   -   -   -   -
ACVR1B  *   -   -   -   -   -   -
ACVR2A  *   -   -   -   -   -   -

"))

Patient_036 = as.data.frame(read.table(text = " Driver  SNV_Organoid_036    INDEL_Organoid_036  Deletion_Organoid_036
ABCB1   *   -   *   -
ACVR1B  *   *   *   -
ACVR2A  *   *   -   -

"))

Patient_021 = as.data.frame(read.table(text = " Driver  SNV_Organoid_021    INDEL_Organoid_021
ABCB1   *   *   -
ACVR1B  *   *   -
ACVR2A  *   *   *

"))

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Patients",
                         tabPanel("Table",theme = "bootstrap.css",

                                  headerPanel("Genomic variations in OESO driver genes"),

                                  sidebarPanel(br(),
                                               tags$style("#select1 {border: 2px solid #dd4b39;}"), div(

                                                 id = "loading-content",

                                                 h2("Binary output"), navbarPageWithText(

                                                   "* means that gene carries an event",

                                                   text = "- means that no event has been observed"

                                                 )

                                               ),
                                    selectInput(
                                      "table_dataset",
                                      "Choose patient:",
                                      choices = c("Patient_005","Patient_013","Patient_036","Patient_021")
                                    ) 
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
                         ),
                         tabPanel("Image",
                                  sidebarPanel( br(),
                                                tags$style("#select2 {background-color:blue;}"),
                                    selectInput(
                                      "image_dataset",
                                      "Choose image:",
                                      choices = c("Mutational_Signatures"="https://i.ibb.co/hZYc9nM/Mutational-Signatures1.png", "Total_and_Minor_Copy_Number" = "https://i.ibb.co/pRYxfwF/Total-and-Minor-Copy-Number.png", "Structural_Variations" = "https://i.ibb.co/JB4z6y6/Strutural-Variations.png", "Statistics" = "https://i.ibb.co/DYm2nm4/Statistics.png" , "Major_and_Minor_Copy_Number" = "https://i.ibb.co/ZV3DTXN/Major-and-Minor-Copy-Number.png", "Mutational_consequences_SNVs" = "https://i.ibb.co/CpyqRdr/Mutational-consequences.png" , "Mutational_consequences_INDEL" = "https://i.ibb.co/Vt4nwqd/Mutational-consequences-indel.png" , "Segment_mean" = "https://i.ibb.co/Cthk4ZD/Segment-mean.png" , "RNA_seq_Driver_Genes" = "https://i.ibb.co/qr9cvdN/RNA-seq.png"
                                      )
                                    ) 
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(
                                    uiOutput("image") 
                                  ), div(

                                    id = "loading-content",

                                    h2("Loading..."), navbarPageWithText(

                                      "Images of",

                                      text = "Organoid models"

                                    )

                                  )
                         ),tags$head(
                           tags$style(type = 'text/css', 
                                      HTML('.navbar { background-color: skin-blue;}
                          .navbar-default .navbar-brand{color: black;}
                          .tab-panel{ background-color: skin-blue; color: black}
                          .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
                           .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, 
                           .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
                                color: #555;
                                background-color: pink;
                            }')
                           )
                         )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Related to displaying tables
  table_data <- reactive({
    switch(input$table_dataset, "Patient_005" = Patient_005 ,"Patient_013" = Patient_013,"Patient_036" = Patient_036,"Patient_021" = Patient_021)
  })
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(table_data())%>% 
  formatStyle(
  'Driver', 
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("0", "1"), c('green', 'red'))
  )
  })

  # Related to displaying images
  output$image <- renderUI({
    tags$img(src = input$image_dataset)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

By

```
%>% 
      formatStyle(
      'Driver', 
      backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("0", "1"), c('green', 'red'))
      )

I am only making the first column red
```

In this app I want cells with * and - in table being colored by red and green respectively but I don't know how to do that.

Any help please

Comment: See https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `formatStyle` with `DT` you can change styles based on that column or a different column.

```
Tumour_005=read.table(text = "     Gene Mutation
                          1    TP53        - 
                          2   ERBB2        -
                          3  PIK3CA        -
                          4    KRAS        -
                          5     MET        -
                          6   CCNE1        -
                          7    CDK6        -
                          8   FBXW7        -
                          9   CCND3        -
                          10 CDKN2A        *")

library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("viewdataradio","View data by:", choices = c("patient", "Image"), inline = TRUE, selected = "patient"),
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose patient:", 
                  choices = c("Tumour_005"))
    ),  
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table") ,
      uiOutput("img")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  observe({
    if(input$viewdataradio == "patient"){
      choices = c("Tumour_005")
      firstchoice = "Tumour_005"
      label = "Choose patient:"
    }else{
      choices = c("Image1")
      firstchoice = "Image1"
      label = "Choose Image:"
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "dataset", label = label, choices = choices, selected = firstchoice)
  })

  data <- reactive({
    data = switch(input$dataset,
                  "Tumour_005" = Tumour_005,
                  "Image1" = Image1
    )

  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(data()) %>% 
      formatStyle(
      'Mutation', 
      backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("-", "*"), c('green', 'red'))
      )

  })

  observe({
    input$dataset
    isolate({
      if (input$dataset == "Image1") {
        output$img <- renderUI({
          tags$img(src = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/43682980/57538542-8c45da00-7340-11e9-81c8-2a023fb050eb.png")
        })
      } 
    })
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

*Based on OP Edit*

I am assuming you want each column to be independent for the color and not have the entire row based on a single column. See below, you just make the columns into a vector.

```
navbarPageWithText <- function(..., text) {

  navbar <- navbarPage(...)

  textEl <- tags$p(class = "navbar-text", text)

  navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]] <- htmltools::tagAppendChild(

    navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]], textEl)

  navbar

}



# Call this function with an input (such as `textInput("text", NULL, "Search")`) if you

# want to add an input to the navbar

navbarPageWithInputs <- function(..., inputs) {

  navbar <- navbarPage(...)

  form <- tags$form(class = "navbar-form", inputs)

  navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]] <- htmltools::tagAppendChild(

    navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]], form)

  navbar

}
library(shiny)
library(DT)
Patient_005=as.data.frame(read.table(text = "   Driver  SNV_Tumour_005  SNV_Organoid_005    INDEL_Tumour_005    INDEL_Organoid_005  Deletion_Organoid_005
                                     ABCB1   *   *   *   -   -   -
                                     ACVR1B  *   *   -   -   -   -
                                     ACVR2A  *   -   -   -   -   -

                                     "))

Patient_013=as.data.frame(read.table(text = "   Driver  SNV_Tumour_013  SNV_Organoid_013    INDEL_Tumour_013    INDEL_Organoid_013  Deletion_Tumour_013 Deletion_Organoid_013
                                     ABCB1   *   -   *   -   -   -   -
                                     ACVR1B  *   -   -   -   -   -   -
                                     ACVR2A  *   -   -   -   -   -   -

                                     "))

Patient_036 = as.data.frame(read.table(text = " Driver  SNV_Organoid_036    INDEL_Organoid_036  Deletion_Organoid_036
                                       ABCB1   *   -   *   -
                                       ACVR1B  *   *   *   -
                                       ACVR2A  *   *   -   -

                                       "))

Patient_021 = as.data.frame(read.table(text = " Driver  SNV_Organoid_021    INDEL_Organoid_021
                                       ABCB1   *   *   -
                                       ACVR1B  *   *   -
                                       ACVR2A  *   *   *

                                       "))

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Patients",
                         tabPanel("Table",theme = "bootstrap.css",

                                  headerPanel("Genomic variations in OESO driver genes"),

                                  sidebarPanel(br(),
                                               tags$style("#select1 {border: 2px solid #dd4b39;}"), div(

                                                 id = "loading-content",

                                                 h2("Binary output"), navbarPageWithText(

                                                   "* means that gene carries an event",

                                                   text = "- means that no event has been observed"

                                                 )

                                               ),
                                               selectInput(
                                                 "table_dataset",
                                                 "Choose patient:",
                                                 choices = c("Patient_005","Patient_013","Patient_036","Patient_021")
                                               ) 
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
                         ),
                         tabPanel("Image",
                                  sidebarPanel( br(),
                                                tags$style("#select2 {background-color:blue;}"),
                                                selectInput(
                                                  "image_dataset",
                                                  "Choose image:",
                                                  choices = c("Mutational_Signatures"="https://i.ibb.co/hZYc9nM/Mutational-Signatures1.png", "Total_and_Minor_Copy_Number" = "https://i.ibb.co/pRYxfwF/Total-and-Minor-Copy-Number.png", "Structural_Variations" = "https://i.ibb.co/JB4z6y6/Strutural-Variations.png", "Statistics" = "https://i.ibb.co/DYm2nm4/Statistics.png" , "Major_and_Minor_Copy_Number" = "https://i.ibb.co/ZV3DTXN/Major-and-Minor-Copy-Number.png", "Mutational_consequences_SNVs" = "https://i.ibb.co/CpyqRdr/Mutational-consequences.png" , "Mutational_consequences_INDEL" = "https://i.ibb.co/Vt4nwqd/Mutational-consequences-indel.png" , "Segment_mean" = "https://i.ibb.co/Cthk4ZD/Segment-mean.png" , "RNA_seq_Driver_Genes" = "https://i.ibb.co/qr9cvdN/RNA-seq.png"
                                                  )
                                                ) 
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(
                                    uiOutput("image") 
                                  ), div(

                                    id = "loading-content",

                                    h2("Loading..."), navbarPageWithText(

                                      "Images of",

                                      text = "Organoid models"

                                    )

                                  )
                         ),tags$head(
                           tags$style(type = 'text/css', 
                                      HTML('.navbar { background-color: skin-blue;}
                          .navbar-default .navbar-brand{color: black;}
                          .tab-panel{ background-color: skin-blue; color: black}
                          .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
                           .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, 
                           .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
                                color: #555;
                                background-color: pink;
                            }')
                           )
                         )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Related to displaying tables
  table_data <- reactive({
    switch(input$table_dataset, "Patient_005" = Patient_005 ,"Patient_013" = Patient_013,"Patient_036" = Patient_036,"Patient_021" = Patient_021)
  })
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(table_data()) %>% 
      formatStyle(
        c('Driver','SNV_Tumour_005','SNV_Organoid_005','INDEL_Tumour_005','INDEL_Organoid_005','Deletion_Organoid_005'), 
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("*", "-"), c('green', 'red'))
      )
  })

  # Related to displaying images
  output$image <- renderUI({
    tags$img(src = input$image_dataset)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

**Edited again based on OP requirement**

I only showed it working with the first two selections, the idea is the same to add the rest of them.

```
navbarPageWithText <- function(..., text) {

  navbar <- navbarPage(...)

  textEl <- tags$p(class = "navbar-text", text)

  navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]] <- htmltools::tagAppendChild(

    navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]], textEl)

  navbar

}



# Call this function with an input (such as `textInput("text", NULL, "Search")`) if you

# want to add an input to the navbar

navbarPageWithInputs <- function(..., inputs) {

  navbar <- navbarPage(...)

  form <- tags$form(class = "navbar-form", inputs)

  navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]] <- htmltools::tagAppendChild(

    navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]], form)

  navbar

}
library(shiny)
library(DT)
Patient_005=as.data.frame(read.table(text = "   Driver  SNV_Tumour_005  SNV_Organoid_005    INDEL_Tumour_005    INDEL_Organoid_005  Deletion_Organoid_005
                                     ABCB1   *   *   *   -   -   -
                                     ACVR1B  *   *   -   -   -   -
                                     ACVR2A  *   -   -   -   -   -

                                     "))

Patient_013=as.data.frame(read.table(text = "   Driver  SNV_Tumour_013  SNV_Organoid_013    INDEL_Tumour_013    INDEL_Organoid_013  Deletion_Tumour_013 Deletion_Organoid_013
                                     ABCB1   *   -   *   -   -   -   -
                                     ACVR1B  *   -   -   -   -   -   -
                                     ACVR2A  *   -   -   -   -   -   -

                                     "))

Patient_036 = as.data.frame(read.table(text = " Driver  SNV_Organoid_036    INDEL_Organoid_036  Deletion_Organoid_036
                                       ABCB1   *   -   *   -
                                       ACVR1B  *   *   *   -
                                       ACVR2A  *   *   -   -

                                       "))

Patient_021 = as.data.frame(read.table(text = " Driver  SNV_Organoid_021    INDEL_Organoid_021
                                       ABCB1   *   *   -
                                       ACVR1B  *   *   -
                                       ACVR2A  *   *   *

                                       "))

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Patients",
                         tabPanel("Table",theme = "bootstrap.css",

                                  headerPanel("Genomic variations in OESO driver genes"),

                                  sidebarPanel(br(),
                                               tags$style("#select1 {border: 2px solid #dd4b39;}"), div(

                                                 id = "loading-content",

                                                 h2("Binary output"), navbarPageWithText(

                                                   "* means that gene carries an event",

                                                   text = "- means that no event has been observed"

                                                 )

                                               ),
                                               selectInput(
                                                 "table_dataset",
                                                 "Choose patient:",
                                                 choices = c("Patient_005","Patient_013","Patient_036","Patient_021")
                                               ) 
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
                         ),
                         tabPanel("Image",
                                  sidebarPanel( br(),
                                                tags$style("#select2 {background-color:blue;}"),
                                                selectInput(
                                                  "image_dataset",
                                                  "Choose image:",
                                                  choices = c("Mutational_Signatures"="https://i.ibb.co/hZYc9nM/Mutational-Signatures1.png", "Total_and_Minor_Copy_Number" = "https://i.ibb.co/pRYxfwF/Total-and-Minor-Copy-Number.png", "Structural_Variations" = "https://i.ibb.co/JB4z6y6/Strutural-Variations.png", "Statistics" = "https://i.ibb.co/DYm2nm4/Statistics.png" , "Major_and_Minor_Copy_Number" = "https://i.ibb.co/ZV3DTXN/Major-and-Minor-Copy-Number.png", "Mutational_consequences_SNVs" = "https://i.ibb.co/CpyqRdr/Mutational-consequences.png" , "Mutational_consequences_INDEL" = "https://i.ibb.co/Vt4nwqd/Mutational-consequences-indel.png" , "Segment_mean" = "https://i.ibb.co/Cthk4ZD/Segment-mean.png" , "RNA_seq_Driver_Genes" = "https://i.ibb.co/qr9cvdN/RNA-seq.png"
                                                  )
                                                ) 
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(
                                    uiOutput("image") 
                                  ), div(

                                    id = "loading-content",

                                    h2("Loading..."), navbarPageWithText(

                                      "Images of",

                                      text = "Organoid models"

                                    )

                                  )
                         ),tags$head(
                           tags$style(type = 'text/css', 
                                      HTML('.navbar { background-color: skin-blue;}
                          .navbar-default .navbar-brand{color: black;}
                          .tab-panel{ background-color: skin-blue; color: black}
                          .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
                           .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, 
                           .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
                                color: #555;
                                background-color: pink;
                            }')
                           )
                         )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Related to displaying tables
  table_data <- reactive({
    switch(input$table_dataset, "Patient_005" = Patient_005 ,"Patient_013" = Patient_013,"Patient_036" = Patient_036,"Patient_021" = Patient_021)
  })

  column_data <- reactive({
    switch(input$table_dataset, 
           "Patient_005" = c('Driver','SNV_Tumour_005','SNV_Organoid_005','INDEL_Tumour_005','INDEL_Organoid_005','Deletion_Organoid_005'),
           "Patient_013" = c('SNV_Tumour_013','SNV_Organoid_013','INDEL_Tumour_013','INDEL_Organoid_013','Deletion_Tumour_013','Deletion_Organoid_013')
                             )
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(table_data()) %>% 
      formatStyle(
        column_data(),
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("*", "-"), c('green', 'red'))
      )
  })

  # Related to displaying images
  output$image <- renderUI({
    tags$img(src = input$image_dataset)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Sorry, what happen if I have multiple columns? I have edited my question for an app with multiple columns; Could you have a look please?

Comment: Thank you; But your kindly new response only works for Patient_005 while in pop down menu I have 3 other patients for which nothing being displayed even the previous plain table.

Comment: Your question did not ask for that, you just asked of how to have colors for multiple columns. You've changed the scope twice now. In the future please know what you want at the beginning and make sure it is in the question.

Comment: Thanks a billion and sorry to be too silly in questioning